# RouteUrl not working when site is published in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had this code in my link

```
 <a href="<%$RouteUrl:City=Islamabad %>" runat="server" >Islamabad</a>
```

Its not routing url. The link is just unclickable. I had tried changing  to  and  but still no luck. I had all 3 of them working during offline run through *Visual Studio* but same site is not working in live.

Comment: You mean in local it is working fine but in production it is failing ?

Comment: When published, its failing *href* and *NavigateURL*, not allowing to route url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is the web.config file is not updated in production environment

`<%$ %>` is an ASP.NET Expression Builder. Used for runtime expression binding for control properties through the server tag attributes. Used with AppSettings, ConnectionStrings, or Resources (or your own custom extension, for example to use code-behind properties). These assignments are added to the OnInit() method of the generated class.

Please refer the below articles for complete understanding of Expression builder in asp.net

[Expressions Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)

Creating custom [ExpressionBuilder Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) as you used in your above code.

Comment: So whats the solution? Can't i use  `<%$ %>` ?

Comment: Expression builder can be default used with Appsettings, connectionStrings or Resources. If you want to use custom expression then you need to go for ExpressionBuilder class as mentioned in the above reference article.